# C Program to Print Unique Elements of An Unsorted Array

Tags: c

Basically, i am trying to get 5 unique listings of herbs(in this case) including stock number, price etc.

After getting even 1 listing for my array i want to use a function to display the listings with stock less than 5 along with their unique code(1,2,3..) if there are none print "not running low on any herbs"and have them stored in a text file.

**My question is how to do what i described in the 2nd paragraph. Calling a function in case 2 that will display all herbs with less than 5 in stock and save them in a text file.**

Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define user "kaiti"
#define pass "123pass!"
#define herbs 5

**void stock(int i, int code[herbs], int quantity[herbs])
{   
    for (i=0;i<herbs;i++){
    if(quantity[i]<5)
        printf("%d \t %d",code[i], quantity[i]);        
}
}**


int main()
{
    float price[herbs];
    char username[20], password[20];
    int option, i, code[herbs], quantity[herbs], consumption[herbs], choice;
//-----LOGIN PHASE-----
printf("Please Enter username:");
scanf("%s",username);

printf("\nPlease enter password:");
scanf("%s",password);

while(strcmp(username, user) != 0  || strcmp(password, pass) != 0)
 {
printf("Wrong username or password try again!\n"); 
printf("\nPlease Enter username:");
scanf("%s",&username);

printf("\nPlease enter password:");
scanf("%s",&password);
}

    printf("\nCorrect username and password.\n\nWelcome Mrs.Kaiti!\n\nWhat would you like to do?");
//-----END OF LOGIN PHASE-----

printf("\n(1)Register Herbs.\n**(2)Display herbs with stock less than 5 and store them in a text file.**\n(3)See the recomended daily dosage of a herb.\n(4)Add or deduct quantity of a herb.\n(5)Sell a herb.\nChoice: ");
scanf("%d",&option);

switch( option )
{
    case 1:

        for(i=0;i<herbs;i++){

        printf("Enter herb code: ");
        scanf("%d",&code[i]);
        printf("Enter herb quantity: ");
        scanf("%d",&quantity[i]);
        printf("Enter recomended daily consumption: ");
        scanf("%d",&consumption[i]);
        printf("Enter price: ");
        scanf("%f",&price[i]);
        printf("Add another herb?\n(1)Yes.\n(2)Back to login screen.\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        if (choice == 2)
            return main()   ;
        }

    **case 2:

        printf("The Following herbs have a quantity less than 5: \n Code\t quantity \n");
        stock(i, code, quantity);**
```

Comment: you need a `break` just before `case 2` (but hey you didn't ask any question)

Comment: My question is how to do what i described in the 2nd paragraph :) Calling a function in case 2 that will display all herbs with less than 5 in stock and save them in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to replace `printf` with `fprintf` like this:

```
void stock(int code[herbs], int quantity[herbs])
{   
    int i;
    FILE *f = fopen("herbs_file_name", "w");

    for (i = 0 ; i < herbs ; i++)
    {
        if(quantity[i] < 5)
        {
            fprintf(f, "%d \t %d\n", code[i], quantity[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Note that you don't need to pass `i` - just declare it locally.